# I want to write a Python script to return a SQL result set from a Wordpress database

Tags: python, wordpress

What i did was: i have opened my WordPress admin module, selected my User and then i have created an Application Password name. So, then Wordpress gave me a toke to be called through my Python code.

After that, i have written the below Python code which was supposed to fetch data from my WordPress database. However, i am getting the following error, saying that my table Leads is not a valid table.

```
import petl as etl
import pandas as pd
import cdata.wordpress as mod

connection = mod.connect("Url=https://www.mywebsite.com/wp/wordpress;User=autoresponder;Password=xxx")
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Leads"
resultset = etl.fromdb(connection,SQL)
print(resultset)
```

**Error message:**

```
cursor.execute(query, *args, **kwargs) cdata.wordpress.DatabaseError: is not a valid table.
```

Comment: Is ‘Leads’ *definitely* a table in the database?  According to the error message, it isn’t.  Perhaps it’s ‘leads’?

Comment: If you have a database tool available that can connect to the database, such as phpmyadmin, run the same query "SELECT * FROM Leads" there and see if you get the same error. I agree with S3DEV, it is most likely an incorrect table name.

Comment: [You already asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77320390/i-want-to-write-a-python-script-to-return-a-sql-result-set-from-a-table-which-is). Instead of deleting and reposting the same exact inquiry, you should *edit* your post to include more details beyond what you initially had.

Comment: The driver you’re using here is not exactly standard. Can you link the documentation or source code for it?

Comment: Hi guys, yes i have confirmed by running the SQL instruction "Select * From Leads" from PhPAdmin and got the expected resultset. So, the table name Leads it's correct.

@esqew this is the CData documentation link: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

The driver you’re using is not establishing a direct connection to the underlying database on which WordPress resides. It instead provides a SQL-compliant interface to specific operations available by the WordPress API. As of this writing, [there are only 7 “tables” that can be queried in this manner](https://cdn.cdata.com/help/FWJ/py/pg_alltables.htm):

> - Categories
> - Comments
> - Media
> - Pages
> - Posts
> - Tags
> - Users

As a non-standard table, it doesn’t appear your custom `Leads` table will be accessible with this driver. Why not just connect directly to the MySQL database itself?